# How to straighten all uneven edges at once

Tags: modeling

[image]I was playing around with sculpting and back and forth to edit mode and I noticed that the created mesh has uneven edges after scaling it to 0 in the *Z* axis.  I was wondering if there is a way to straighten all the edges at once. Of course I could do <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> to each and every loop and scale them individually on the y, but that's quite time consuming. And to my knowledge I haven't figured a way to straighten them at once. So, if you guys have any idea please do suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a job for the Mesh Relax addon. It comes with Blender. You have to activate it in the User Preferences.

[image]